# Не срабатывает программное нажатие на кнопку

Tags: c++-cli

Нужно вызвать обработчик события нажатия кнопки при нажатии другой кнопки. Они находятся на разных вкладках tabcontrol'а, если это важно.

```
private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
         ofstream out;
         out.open("Genom/UserSequence.txt");
         marshal_context ^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
         const char* UserSequence = context->marshal_as<const char*>(richTextBox1->Text);
         out << UserSequence;
         textBox1->Text = "Genom/UserSequence.txt";
         //button1_Click(nullptr, nullptr);
         button1->PerformClick();
}
```

При пошаговой проверке до строчки с вызовом доходит, проскакивает, а вот до этой ф-ции уже не доходит

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
// тут много кода, не вижу смысла копировать, до него все равно не доходит
}
```

Закомментированный вариант тоже не работает.
Все кнопки создавались в конструкторе, то есть автоматически прописано их создание. Если вручную нажимать на button1, то все работает.

MS Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

Событие `PreviewKeyDown` поможет Вам.